# Help recreate bass synth like KOOS, Drezo

Tags: sound-design

I have a problem with recreating this bass sound. I think it's a sine wave with white noise and a bit of distortion. But all attempts to recreate this sound were unsuccessful :(

Can anyone help me do this?

Examples:

1) KOOS [1:00]

2) Drezo [1:00] https://soundcloud.com/drezomusic/drezo-x-dustycloud-house#t=1:00

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I dont really make this type of music but tried to get it as close as possible. I dont think its just noise with distortion. There definitely is an oscillator of some sort as the basis of the sound. I started off in Serum by messing with the oscillator shape until I found a good basis.

After that I used a slight 12 db lp filter and cut a very slight amount. I added a Sub which gave it more of a phasing sort of sound.

The Amp Envelope has a fast attack and I shaped it a little to give the same effect as the sample above: See Patch below

[image]

I added some distortion effects that are available on Serum the Hyper and the Distortion:

[image]

After this I went and added another distortion unit. I used Izotope trash but think you can use anyone that has an EQ attached to the distortion. Saturn is another one. There seems to be a lot of saturation on the low end and I would try to experiment with different distortion types on the low end portion of the sound along with the dry/wet signals.

Here is a link to the Serum patch: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pv01uUj2f09CVO2L9nt0PzgtU_SzrZiq You could also mess around with the oscillator shape. EQ as well. Its not exact but think its around the area to start messing around with. Hope that helps